# Orbit of an element $a$ over a set $A$ in the monster model.

Tags: model-theory

> Let $\mathbb{M}$  the monster model of a theory $T$. If the orbit of an element $a$ over a set $A$ of elements reals, $O(a/A)$ is not finite then it must be of the size of $\mathbb{M}.$

In this case the orbit is related to the set $Aut_{A}(\mathbb{M})$ of automorphisms of $ \mathbb{M} $ that fixed the set $ A $, that is  $$ O(a/A)= \{ b \in \mathbb{M}| \exists f \in Aut_{A}(\mathbb{M}), f(a)=b   \} $$
as the monster model has the property that if $$ tp(a/A)=tp(b/A) \Rightarrow \exists f \in Aut_{A}(\mathbb{M}), f(a)=b $$
so I thought to try $tp(a/A)=tp(b/A)$ for all $b \in \mathbb{M}$ so 
for each $b \in \mathbb{M} \ \ \exists f \in Aut_{A}(\mathbb{M}), f(a)=b $ then $b \in O(a/A)$ and done. But I could not see this. Any hint is appreciated. I do not know if my idea is right or no. Thanks

Comment: Four quick comments. 1. You mean $\text{tp}(a/A) = \text{tp}(b/A)$, not $/B$. 2. Of course you don't have $\text{tp}(a/A) = \text{tp}(b/A)$ for *all* $b\in\mathbb{M}$. This could only happen if there was only one type over $A$! 3. It's not clear what you mean by "a set $A$ of elements reals", but you also need to assume that $A$ is a *small* set in order for this to be true. 4. Finally a hint: Use the saturation of the monster model.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(x)={\rm tp}(a/A)$ then $O(a/A)=p(\mathbb M)$. The following type is obviously not realized in $\mathbb M$

$q(x)=p(x)\cup \{b\neq x : b\models p(x)\}$

If $|p(\mathbb M)|<|\mathbb M|$, by saturation, it must be *finitely* inconsistent in $\mathbb M$. But $q(x)$ is finitely consistent whenever $p(\mathbb M)$ is infinite. Hence $O(a/A)=p(\mathbb M)$ is finite.